# legendre solution for non homogenous equation

Tags: legendre-polynomials

given the legendre equation $(1-x^2)y'' - 2xy' + by = f(x)$
why can the solution be a series of legendre polynomials $y(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n P_n(x)$? i thought legndre solves the homogenous version of the equation so wouldn't a series of legendre polynomials all equal 0,
or even more isn't there only 1 legendre polynomial a solution to the equation?

Comment: The $n$-th Legendre polynomial solves the homogeneous equation for $b=n(n+1)$. Not every Legendre polynomial solves the homogeneous equation for any $b$. However, since the Legendre polynomials form a basis of $L^2(-1,1 )$, any solution to the equation that lies in that space can be expressed as a series of Legendre polynomials, so the ansatz for $y(x)= \ldots$ is sensible.

Comment: @DominikS what do u mean by a  L2(−1,1)

Comment: The space of all square integrable functions over that interval, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces_and_Lebesgue_integrals).

Comment: The fact that it is a Sturm Liouville diff. equation could help you.